# Cannot figure out the issue with this SQL CASE

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, casting, case

```
CASE
WHEN CAST(a.category AS VARCHAR) like '%jumpsuits%'   THEN CAST(a.google_product_category AS VARCHAR) = 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > One-Pieces > Jumpsuits & Rompers'
WHEN CAST(a.category AS VARCHAR) like '%knitwear%'    THEN CAST(a.google_product_category AS VARCHAR) = 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses'
WHEN CAST(a.category AS VARCHAR) like '%lounge wear%' THEN CAST(a.google_product_category AS VARCHAR) = 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Shirts & Tops'
ELSE CAST(a.google_product_category AS VARCHAR) END as google_product_category
```

The issue i am facing is: "SYNTAX_ERROR: line 7:6: All CASE results must be the same type: boolean"

I have also joined the table in a previous sub query casting it as a varchar, so there shouldn't be any issues with this.

Anyone have any ideas?

For context i am trying to populate a field that would return a blank where the category is like my "likes" anything else i just want it to remain as it is.

Many thanks

Comment: In your first three branches you have an `=` operation, which yields a Boolean. But the last one is a string. That doesn't match. To get more help you should [edit] the question and post a [example], i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statements, `INSERT INTO` statements for some sample data and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text.

Comment: What data type is `category`? The cast to varchar seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` has expressions returning different data types, which is not allowed. If you're simply trying to update the `google_product_category` based on the `category` column, try something like this:

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (category TEXT, google_product_category TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('Jumpsuit'),('kniTweaR'),('lounge WEAR');
```

Query

```
SELECT category,
  CASE 
    WHEN category ILIKE '%jumpsuit%' 
      THEN 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > One-Pieces > Jumpsuits & Rompers'
    WHEN category ILIKE '%knitwear%' 
      THEN 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses'
    WHEN category ILIKE '%lounge wear%' 
      THEN 'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Shirts & Tops'
  END
FROM t;

  category   |                                case                                 
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Jumpsuit    | Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > One-Pieces > Jumpsuits & Rompers
 kniTweaR    | Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses
 lounge WEAR | Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Shirts & Tops
(3 Zeilen)
```

Comment: @JK1993 glad it helped! If your columns are already text there is no need to cast them, and consider using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` in case you're not 100% sure about the spelling (`LIKE` is case sensitive). Good luck!